# Gradle migrate from 7.5 to 8.0: deprecated configurations dependency

Tags: gradle, dependencies

```
configurations {
      foo
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'group:name:1.0'

      foo "group1:name1:1.0"
      foo "group2:name2:1.0"
      foo "group3:name3:1.0"

      implementation configurations.foo      <---- deprecated
}
```

deprecated warning:

```
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead.
```

How to change the deprecated line for gradle 8.0?

Comment: Could you just do `configurations { foo.extendsFrom implementation }`?  I believe that's what the error message is suggesting.

Comment: configurations.foo is a subset of implementation dependencies. configurations.foo is also used in other places.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to "get 'er done", while thoroughly violating the spirit of the deprecation...

You can just change...

> `implementation configurations.foo`

to

```
configurations.foo.allDependencies.each {
    implementation group: it.group, name: it.name, version: it.version
}
```

Perhaps it's "less confusing" than the other?